# chown: invalid user: ‘user:group’

Tags: chown

sudo chown is resulting in this error.
Can someone please help?

chown: invalid user: ‘user:group’

[Screenshot of Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejRRW.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because screenshots of windows of text outputs are ridiculous.

Comment: but you see the error and know the answer to help, but you do not want to help. <3 this world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually put in your user name and group name - eg

```
sudo chown pt:pt /usr/lib/libcastle
```

Changes the owner of that file to pt and the group also to pt.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem by this command?
Server:/ #
drwxr-xr-x  40 root root  4096 Jun  4 08:25 data
drwxrwxrwt  42 root root  4096 Jun  4 09:09 tmp
SERVER:/ # **chown /data/postgres1 root.postgres postgres1/**
chown: invalid user: ‘/data/postgres1’
Server:/ #